# Access to the path 'D:\Hosting\11920164\html\Admin\ImportData\Reviews.xls' is denied

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Access to the path `'D:\Hosting\11920164\html\Admin\ImportData\Reviews.xls'` is denied.

I have find this error when I try to upload an Excel sheet in reviews folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set Read/Write Permission to **/ImportData**